# Mark points with a value in a MATLAB plot

Tags: matlab, plot

The following command does mark the points with a square, but it does not put a value in (for example, `(21,0)`, ...).

```
X = [21 8 2 1 0]

Y = [0 1 2 3 4]

plot(X,Y,'k-s')
```

Which parameter should I add so all `5` point values come on the plot?

The values can't be typed one by one as they can change, because they are random numbers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can display text on your plot by using the functions [NUM2STR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/num2str.html), [CELLSTR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/cellstr.html), and [STRTRIM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strtrim.html) to format the coordinate values into a cell array of strings and using the function [TEXT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/text.html) to display them:

```
strValues = strtrim(cellstr(num2str([X(:) Y(:)],'(%d,%d)')));
text(X,Y,strValues,'VerticalAlignment','bottom');
```

And your plot will look like this for the sample data above:

[image]

Comment: What if what I want to do is not have a square as a symbol in the plot, but actually have a number Ex: the value in its its axis: so 0 on (0,4), and 8 on (8,1)