# Matlab Marking a Point

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, matlab-figure

I need to mark a point on the following plot:
[image]

Particularly, I need to mark the red line at 25 and it's corresponding y-axis value. How do I do this?

I tried looking [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606958/mark-points-with-a-value-in-a-matlab-plot) but I didn't really understand the solution (what exactly is that code doing??) but I don't know if I want that. I want more of a slanted line with a coordinate, kinda like this:

```
    (2,5)
   /
  /
 /
/
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Do you have to do it programmatically? Because the figure window has a GUI for adding annotations.

Answer (score 3):

Use [ANNOTATION](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/annotation.html) of `textarrow` type. Here is an example from the documentation:

```
plot(1:10);
a = annotation('textarrow', [.3 .5], [.6 .5], 'String' , 'Straight Line');
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**:

Notice that `annotation` requires coordinate in normalized figure units (nfu) that are different from axes units. To convert from axes units to nfu I like to use [DS2NFU](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10656-data-space-to-figure-units-conversion) FileExchange sumbission.

Here is an example using linked question and answer from @gnovice.

```
X = [21 8 2 1 0];
Y = [0 1 2 3 4];
plot(X,Y,'k-s')
strValues = strtrim(cellstr(num2str([X(:) Y(:)],'(%d,%d)')));
% where the arrow should go from
gapx = 1; 
gapy = 0.1;
% axes limits
xl = xlim;
yl = ylim;

for k=1:numel(X)
    % convert X and Y coordinates to figure units
    pos = ds2nfu([X(k), Y(k), gapx, gapy]);
    if X(k)+gapx < xl(2)
        posx = [pos(1)+pos(3) pos(1)];
    else
        posx = [pos(1)-pos(3) pos(1)];
    end
    if Y(k)+gapy < yl(2)
        posy = [pos(2)+pos(4) pos(2)];
    else
        posy = [pos(2)-pos(4) pos(2)];
    end

    annotation('textarrow',posx,posy,'String',strValues{k});
end
```

[image]

Comment: But how would you position the arrow head to be where at 25 on the x-axis? Is it just a percentage thing so that if the axis goes from 0 - 40 then `x(2)` should equal `25/40` ?

Comment: @yuk what Dan said, I don't understand how to control the position of this arrow.

Comment: Regarding the positioning of this arrow, see also: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/positioning-annotations-in-data-space.html.  Specifically, running the following addpath  (`addpath([docroot '/techdoc/creating_plots/examples'])`) exposes a function called `dsxy2figxy`.

Comment: @Pursuit: I think it worth a separate answer.

Comment: @Yuk:  Added.  [more characters to reach minimum]

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly an adjunct to yuk's already complete answer.  Turns out that Matlab ships with a tool to perform the axis --> figure coordinate transformations.  See a discussion at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/positioning-annotations-in-data-space.html.  This page also includes examples of using the "textarrow" annotation.

---

**TL;DR:**

```
addpath([docroot '/techdoc/creating_plots/examples'])
```

Exposes a function called `dsxy2figxy`.

---

**Example use:**

```
%Perform the addpath (this is relativly slow, try to only do it once.)
addpath([docroot '/techdoc/creating_plots/examples'])  %Needed for dsxy2figxy

%Create some figure to look at
figure(219376); clf
x = linspace(0.8, 40, 1000);
y = 1./x;
plot(x,y, 'b-')
hold on

%Mark position 100
tipXy  = dsxy2figxy(gca, x(100),   y(100));
tailXy = dsxy2figxy(gca, mean(x), mean(y));
h = annotation('textarrow', [tailXy(1) tipXy(1)], [tailXy(1) tipXy(1)],...
    'String',['  (' num2str(x(100)) ',' num2str(x(100)) ')']);
```